# How to write unit test case to access unit of work?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, unit-of-work

I wrote unit test case to test the add user method. when I mock unitofwork and pass it through constructor. It shows error like can't instantiate proxy of class.could not find parameterless constructor.

constructor of code which I need to test:

```
public class UserManagement : IUserManagement
{
    #region Property declarations

    private readonly IEntityBaseRepository<User> _userRepository;

    private readonly IEntityBaseRepository<Role> _roleRepository;

    private readonly IEntityBaseRepository<UserStatus> _userStatusRepository;

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    private readonly IEncryptionService _encryptionService;

    private readonly IEntityBaseRepository<ForgotPassword> _forgotPassword;



    #endregion

    public UserManagement(
        IEntityBaseRepository<User> userRepository,
        IEntityBaseRepository<Role> roleRepository,
        IEntityBaseRepository<UserStatus> userStatusRepository,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        IEncryptionService encryptionService,
        IEntityBaseRepository<ForgotPassword> forgotPassword)

    {
        this._userRepository = userRepository;
        this._roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this._userStatusRepository = userStatusRepository;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this._encryptionService = encryptionService;
        this._forgotPassword = forgotPassword;

    }
```

Method:
 I have passed the unit of work through constructor ,still it breaks at _unitOfwork.commit()

public ResponseDTO AddUser(User user, string currentUserName)
        {
            var response = new ResponseDTO();

```
        try
        {

            User currentUser = this._userRepository.GetUserByUserName(currentUserName.Trim().ToLower());

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (!this._userRepository
                    .FindBy(s => s.Email.Trim().ToLower() == user.Email.ToLower().Trim() && s.IsDeleted == false)
                        .Any())
                {
                    if (!this._userRepository.FindBy(
                                s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.MobileNumber)
                                && s.MobileNumber == user.MobileNumber && s.IsDeleted == false).Any())
                    {
                        var newUser = new User()
                        {
                            LastName = user.LastName,
                            FirstName = user.FirstName,
                            Username = user.Username,
                            Email = user.Email,
                            HashedPassword = user.HashedPassword,
                            Salt = user.Salt,
                            AreaCode = user.AreaCode,
                            MobileNumber = user.MobileNumber,
                            RoleId = user.RoleId,
                            Address = user.Address,
                            CreatedByUserId = currentUser.Id,
                            UserStatusId = (int)Enumerations.UserStatus.Active
                        };

                        this._userRepository.Add(newUser);

                        this._unitOfWork.Commit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.IsSuccess = false;
                        response.UserMessage = "Contact number is already in use.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    response.IsSuccess = false;
                    response.UserMessage = "The email is already in use.";
                }
            }

            response.IsSuccess = true;

            response.UserMessage = user.Username + " user created successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.IsSuccess = false;
            response.TechMessage = ex.Message;
        }

        return response;
    }

    Test case :


    public void AddUser()
    {



        var userRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<User>>();
        var roleRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Role>>();
        var userStatusRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<UserStatus>>();
        var unitOfWork = new Mock<UnitOfWork>();
        var encryptRep = new Mock<IEncryptionService>();
        var forgetPasswordRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<ForgotPassword>>();

        var sut = new UserManagement(userRep.Object, roleRep.Object, userStatusRep.Object, unitOfWork.Object, encryptRep.Object, forgetPasswordRep.Object);
        User userDetail = new User();
        userDetail.FirstName = "jkkj";
        userDetail.LastName = "jjk";
        userDetail.Username = "sff";
        userDetail.Email = "grs@gmail.com";
        userDetail.RoleId = 1;
        Assert.AreEqual(true, sut.AddUser(userDetail, "superadmin").IsSuccess);

    }
```

Comment: Ok, but post your entire code of the `AddUser` method to see how to mock everything. The code of your `ResponseDTO`

Comment: Edited and added the complete code of AddUser method

Comment: _"Method:Breaks at unitofwork.commit"_ - read [ask] and research the actual error, show what you have found and why that didn't work.

Comment: please add you unit test (and mocking) code

Comment: Added at end public void AddUser() method with heading as test case

Answer (score -1):

Why are you passing null in following line:

var unitOfWork = new Mock(null);

Try not to pass null here or you can define a parameter less constructor in UnitOfWork class.

Comment: As per your suggestion,removed null and added parameter less constructor in unit of work class.It shows object reference not set to an instance.

Comment: I already have this constructor in that class  public UnitOfWork(IDbFactory dbFactory)
        {
            this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
        }

Comment: Public unitofwork is not a parameter less constuctor. It is accepting the parameter.

Comment: yes . I don't know how to pass IDbfactory as parameter of unit of work while mocking in unit test case since it is a interface